# Maximum file serving speeds capable by arduino? (TCP/FTP/WiFi/Bluetooth/RS232)

Tags: arduino, wifi, fileserver

First up please note I am on the arduino forums but despite a few weeks of researching and experimentation I've not had much luck. I've greatly benefited from this forum in C# so thought I'd try my luck with an arduino question.

I'm very interested to know the **maximum transfer speeds that have been achieved by an Arduino** acting as a file server using the various network protocols such as RS232 vs Bluetooth vs TCP vs FTP vs Wifi. If someone has done a proper comparison I'd love to see it.

I've been scouring the net over the last few weeks and have found various webserver examples, and implemented a few myself, but I still can't seem to get the transfer speeds I need. The BEST rate I've got so far is 80kB/s via ethernet webserver, and about 20kB/s via WiFi. I've read of people getting 240kB/s via ethernet on custom light FTP servers so I know it's got to be possible to improve my speeds. I'm guessing it's my newb SPI and buffering code that might be inefficient. I've outlined some summary info below. I'd really appreciate any input on this from the pros!

And just to clarify - the arduino is the file server not the client for this scenario, and is serving files from the SD card to a client computer. Both are sharing the SPI bus.

**My Setup**

Ethermega (ATMega256)

SD Card (via SPI)

[ATWINC1500](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATWINC1500) WiFi  (IEEE 802.11 b/g/n running on SPI).

File Serve Method: HTTP Webserver accessed by a client browser
   (Console access for RS232).

**MAXIMUM SPEEDS ACHIEVED**

**RS232: 14kB/s**

Via console I can serve large files direct from the SD card at around 14KB/s at 115200 baud (which is essentially the bit rate in short distance digital serial comms). As expected.

**Bluetooth: ?**

Not tested yet. I understand  the bluetooth protocol supports up to 50Mbit/s in theory, however in reality Bluetooth 4.1 you can get about 1Mb/s (125kB/s) and the upcoming Bluetooth 5 is touted for 2Mb/s (333kB/s) max throughput (wikipedia).  I suspect performance may also be severely constrained on a microcontroller like arduino. I'm guessing you might double 114200baud speeds to say 30kB/s?

**HTTP webserver - Ethernet (TCP/IP): 80kB/s**

I implemented [Sean Ashton's WebDAVNav][2] web based file server and modified it to server HTML not XML. Got it serving files from the SD card at 80kB/s. Tried to get [sirleech's Webduino][3] server going to no avail.

**HTTP webserver - WiFi (TCP/IP): 20kB/s**

I modified standard WiFi Webserver and coded SPI handling to share the SPI Wifi and SD card to serve files via HTTP GET method. It worked but is horrendously slow. After optimising my loops as best as possible, using a 1024 byte buffer, low level C calls to bypass the DigitalWrite/Read methods, I managed to get 20kB/s. I also looked at the [Jaycar example][4] of a WiFi webserver, however it uses the older style WiFi shield that uses serial, not SPI. So it's limited to serving at 500bytes/second.

**Ethernet FTP fileserver (TCP/IP): ?**

Not tested. I haven't implemented a light FTP server. I've read of people [claiming 255kB/s](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=182382.60) transfer speeds using a Due. This is impressive.

Basically I'm trying to get the best possible wireless transfer speeds from an 8bit embedded microcontroller (ATMEGA256), such as an Arduino Ethermega, preferably by hosting a simple WiFi HTTP file server so the client browser can connect to it as a hotspot and rapidly download files from the SD card.

Any help would be appreciated and I hope this question is of relevance to the community. 
Dan